# How to use default calendar without google account?

Tags: android, calendar

Hi I am developing a tablet app for employees in an organization. Users will get some event details from server and those events should be added to native calendar in the device. Since it is an official device users may or may not add google accounts. My first question is whether a default android calendar will work without syncing with any mail account? If not is it possible to sync any microsoft account or company mail account instead of google account?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to edit existing mobile calendar then use "Calendar Provider"

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html

Or other method to create separate calendar for your own app.

To use calendar in android. Implement this in XML.

```
<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />
```

And Activity class :-

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.widget.CalendarView;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class CalendarValue extends AppCompatActivity {

CalendarView calendarView;
TextView dateDisplay;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.android_calendar_view_example);

    calendarView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    dateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_display);
    dateDisplay.setText("Date: ");

    calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView calendarView, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            dateDisplay.setText("Date: " + i2 + " / " + i1 + " / " + i);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected Date:\n" + "Day = " + i2 + "\n" + "Month = " + i1 + "\n" + "Year = " + i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Get the value from the calendar and use it as you want to use.

Comment: I want to add events to native calendar...dont want to implement calendar in my app

Comment: Just Edited my ans. Plz see.

Comment: As i mentioned in question I am not sure whether some mail accounts will be synced in the device. In that case what i will do?

Comment: @seethalakshmi, Ofcourse yes, If sync will on . Because you are using native calendar of mobile. If sync is off then you can achieve your goal...